# Bind default value of a checkbox to angular model where true & false are represented as 'Yes' & 'No'?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I need to set the default value of a checkbox input to its existing value per the model (being 'quote.user.tracker'), and then change the value in the model as it is selected or deselected (no problem here). This is complicated by the fact that the model value is represented by 'Yes'/'No' strings rather than true/false.

quote.user.tracker: 'quote' is my controller, 'user' the entire object and 'tracker' the specific attribute.

I cannot get the checkbox to reflect the correct starting value.

My current code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Tracker" id="Tracker" ng-checked="quote.user.tracker='Yes'" ng-model="quote.user.tracker">
```

I have tried using ng-show below additionally, but to no avail:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Tracker" id="Tracker" ng-show="quote.user.tracker='Yes'"ng-model="quote.user.tracker" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="Tracker" id="Tracker" ng-show="quote.user.tracker='No'"ng-model="quote.user.tracker" checked>
```

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

= is assigning

== or === is comparison

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Tracker" id="Tracker" ng-show="quote.user.tracker==='Yes'"ng-model="quote.user.tracker" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="Tracker" id="Tracker" ng-show="quote.user.tracker==='No'"ng-model="quote.user.tracker" checked>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `ng-checked` with `ng-model`. From the [docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/docs/api/ng/directive/ngChecked):

> Note that this directive should not be used together with `ngModel`, as this can lead to unexpected behavior.

You could use `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value`, like this:

```
<input type="checkbox"
       name="Tracker"
       id="Tracker"
       ng-true-value="'Yes'" 
       ng-false-value="'No'" 
       ng-model="quote.user.tracker">
```

Comment: Thanks Merrott - that's exactly what I did; used ng-checked === 'Yes' and the ng-true-value='Yes' and ng-false-value='No' options. Major issue was use of an assignment operator as per Praveen's answer above.  Many thanks.